# Hive to Redshift Date/Time Conversion

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-redshift

I recently moved data stored in Hadoop to Redshift, the time field in the Hadoop data is stored as a STRING.  In Redshift the field is VARCHAR(20).  The format of the date STRING in Hadoop is, "YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MI-SS".

I am trying to find the time difference (in seconds) between two time fields in Redshift but seem to be having trouble formatting the dates correctly.  I know how to use the DATEDIFF function, but am unable to properly format the incoming date STRING from Hadoop to Redshift.  Using the TO_DATE(trans_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS) function only returns values in the form of 'YYYY-MM-DD', the remainder hour, minutes, seconds is truncated.

Any thoughts?

I was able to get this to work, seems pretty cumbersome and inefficient...

```
select
trans_time, 
datediff(second, '2015-05-31 00:00:00', 
    cast(to_date(trans_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
            || ' ' || 
            split_part(trans_time, '-', 4) 
            || ':' || 
            split_part(trans_time, '-', 5) 
            || ':' || 
            split_part(trans_time, '-', 6) AS TIMESTAMP)) 
from <table_name>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I could come up with is to redesign my table with a TIMESTAMP column instead of the VARCHAR.  In the COPY function I have to designate,

```
timeformat 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MI-SS'
```